# Switch doesn't work until I press it

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, uiswitch, avaudiosession

I made a UISwitch for overriding the silent switch and the code is as follows:

```
@IBAction  func `switch`(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    defaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "OverrideSwitch2")
    if (sender.isOn == true) {
       overridesound()
    } else {
       disableoverride()
    }
}

func overridesound() {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        //print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Sender is on")
        } catch _ as NSError {
            //print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch _ as NSError {
        //print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func disableoverride() {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        //print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
            print("Sender is off")
        } catch _ as NSError {
            //print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch _ as NSError {
        //print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

When the switch is on, it overrides the silent switch and when it's off, the silent switch works as normal. However, when starting up the app it's silent by default (even if the switch state is on) and I have to toggle the switch  to get it working. I have created an NSUserDefault for the switch and was hoping the switch would run the function by default when it's on, but it's not the case.

The switch does work but it won't run the functions until I interact with it. How do I fix this?

Comment: The functions you have are literally only triggered when the switch is tapped. You would need to call your other function (e.g. `overridesound()` in the view controller’s `viewDidLoad()` method. You could do this after checking user defaults for the current saved value.

Comment: @Chris is right. An `IBAction()` is effected on tap. You want to have the code called when the view loads if you want the set functionality without tapping a button.

Comment: @Jake An `IBAction` is called when the event it is connected to occurs. It doesn't have to be a tap. In the case of a `UISwitch`, the action is most likely connected to the "value changed" event.

Comment: I tried messing around with ViewDidLoad today and tried to create a function with a switch statement that would run there. I connected the switch via an outlet but that didn't seem to work for me. I feel really close, just trying to figure out an implementation that works.